# don't understand "self" error

Tags: python, function, selenium

Please forgive the noob question. I don't understand this "self" stuff in relation to this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def is_element_present(self, how, what):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True

#### navigate to the web page with a bunch of code here, then continue

text_present = self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Click Here"))
```

When I run this, here's the error I get:

```
        test_link = self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.LINK_TEXT, "Click Here"))
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I understand "self" is used by convention as the first argument in a function but I don't understand the error.  How do I define self?

Edit 1: I stand corrected on where "self" is used by convention (see comments/answers below).  However, I still don't know what I should be doing to satisfy the Python interpreter.

Comment: What do you intend `self` to be?  Your code never creates any objects at all.

Comment: `self` is used as the first argument in instance methods not functions. There is a pretty significant difference between the two.

Comment: `self` is not used by convention as the first argument in a function.  Consider spending some time with one of the various "learning python" tutorials available on the net (e.g., [this](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) or [this](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python)).

Comment: I'm not sure what I intend self to be. What I really want is a boolean, which I thought the function would provide. I've tried creating a variable, like "text = self.assertTrue(..." , but I get the same error.  Thanks for the clarification IanAuld and larsks

Comment: Also please don't do this: `try: do_some_stuff()` all on one line. Hit return and properly indent it, spaces not tabs.

Comment: Re-read my answer carefully (and follw that link!). I improved it, so it should become clear what the problem is.

Comment: Jeff, you really should read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)! Do you actaully have any idea about the concept of classes, instances, and how functions work - in general?

Comment: Well, yes, in general terms, very general. But, even though I've coded some fairly complicated stuff in the past, sometimes I just can't get my head wrapped around these ideas. For example, I'm still a bit stumped about my original issue; where do I get the "self" whatever to plug in here. Is it a variable I have to create? In any event, I really really appreciate all the comments here. I'm going to read up with some of the "read up" suggestions here.  Thanks, all!!

Answer (score 0):

`self` is "used by convention as the first argument" in a *method*, which is associated with a class. `self` in this context represents the instance of the class that is calling the method. A function, however, is not associated with a class, and thus no initial `self` argument is required. This is one of the fundamental differences between functions and methods--methods are associated with a class, and are called as `instanceOfClass.methodName(args)`, where functions simply exist in the namespace and are called as `functionName(args)`. Also note that when *calling* a method, `self` is not passed to the call: it is only used when defining the method.

Comment: Just the name `self` is convention. The first argument is actually given by the language itself.

Comment: I thought I made that clear in the last sentence when I said that `self` is only used in the method definition, not when calling the method (since the instance you are referring to was provided before the dot).

Comment: You might have thought, but you actually did not. These are different aspects: calling and being called. Also, this is wrong: Of course is the object (note the difference: I do not call it `self`) passed to the method: as the **first** argument; within the object, it can then be referenced by then first argument's name. And _that_ (the name, not the argument as such) would be `self` - just by convention  I tried to detail this in my answer, welcome to leave a comment if that is still not clear.

Comment: @Olaf So let me make sure I have this straight: A method's first argument is the object calling the method (which by convention is given the name `self`), which Python automatically passes when the method is called, along with any additional arguments specified between the parentheses. So `objectInstance.nameOfMethod(arg1, arg2)` really has three arguments: `objectInstance` (which is passed automatically by Python), `arg1` and `arg2`, and would be defined `def nameOfMethod(self, someArg, otherArg)`, with `objectInstance` being passed for `self`, `arg1` for `someArg` and `arg2` for `otherArg`.

Comment: Wel,, yes. That's exactly what the method signature says. Remember: "explicit is better than implicit". Actually, in Java you have somethig similar, also in C++, if we ignore the additional pointer-syntax (historical reasons: no reference types). For the latter languages, it is only that `this` can be omitted, as the compiler uses object-scope within a method when resolving a symbol name first (method).

Comment: Actually, in Python you can even bind a function to an object with some meta-programming magic using the `types.MethodType()` class. Actually is that what is done normally by the metaclass for each function defined: it is bound to the instances. That's pretty tight to magic if you are not familar with that. For instance the new Enum class uses that a lot as I have learned recently.

Answer (score 0):

You might know about the `this` pointer in C++. In priciple, Python's `self` is quite similar (but is more a reference than a pointer). It is the current object you apply the function to.

```
class MyClass:
    def my_method(self, arg):
        pass

my_object = MyClass()
my_object.my__method("whatever")
```

is actually like (not exactly identical to):

```
def my_func(the_object, arg):
    pass

class MyClass:
    pass

my_object = MyClass()
my_func(my_object, "whatever")
```

As there is actually more involved, the other way round will not work:

```
my_object.my_func("whatever")
```

Will raise an exception (an error), just try it. That is because `my_func` is an *unbound function* (not related to any object/class). `my_method` actually is `bound` (to `my_object`).

While `this` is passed implicitly (you do not have to specify it as an argument) to a method in C++, Python requires it to be listed explicitly as the first argument. The name `self` is actually just convention, a method will always get its object as the first argument, so it could also be named "thats_me". However, stick to `self', as many tools rely on this (syntax highlighting editors, debuggers, ...).

In the method itself, all members of the object are then accessed explicitly by `self.my_member` or `self`.my_func()`. While in C++ one would write`my_member`or`this->my_member`, etcetera. The latter is basically similar to Python's way.

Please read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) and in the tutorial in general.

**Background:** Passing the object expliticly as the first argument is due to one of Pythons major guidelines: "explicit is better than implicit".